# Not able to find Web API route?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I’m struggling to figure out why I can’t get to an API end point. I’m building a Web API that will be calling another local API and from everything I see it should be getting to the end point and I’m looking for any ideas.

This is the code in the originating API. I’m using RestSharp to make the call.

```
string jsonToSend = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(m);

var request = new RestRequest("CheckForDuplicateID", Method.POST);     
request.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", jsonToSend, ParameterType.RequestBody);
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.AddParameter("CandidateID", m.CandidateID);     
request.AddParameter("FirstName", m.FirstName);         
request.AddParameter("LastName", m.LastName);

var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:60077/api/IDM/");
var content = client.Execute(request).Content;
```

This is the end point in the secondary API where I'm trying to get to.

```
[HttpPost]
public static DuplicateCheck CheckForDuplicateID([FromBody] DuplicateCheck m)
{
    ....code 
}
```

This is my RouteConfig.cs file. I've tried both routes and neither one works.

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services

    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }

    //config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    //    name: "DefaultApi",
    //    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    //    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

When I fire up the secondary API locally it is running on `localhost:60077` which I hard coded above. The name of my controller is IDMController and this is the message I get but the URL looks correct to me.

```
{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:60077/api/IDM/CheckForDuplicateID'.","MessageDetail":"No type was found that matches the controller named 'IDM'."}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actions must be instance members of the `ApiController`, not `static`.

```
[HttpPost]
public DuplicateCheck CheckForDuplicateID([FromBody] DuplicateCheck m) {
    ....code 
}
```

Since attribute routing is enabled with

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

consider using attribute routing on the API controller to get the desired behavior

```
[RoutePrefix("api/IDM")]
public class IDMController : ApiController {

    //...

    //POST api/IDM/CheckForDuplicateID
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("CheckForDuplicateID")]
    public DuplicateCheck CheckForDuplicateID([FromBody] DuplicateCheck m) {
        ....code 
    }
}
```

Reference [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

Comment: I added this to the top of the action but didn't seem to work either. Same message that is can't find the route. [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/IDM")]

Comment: @Caverman recheck the provided answer carefully. Note the attributes used and also that the action should not be `static`

Comment: Thanks for the help! Went back and looked through what I was doing and read the answer again. Added the Route and RoutePrefix like you said and removed the static declaration. At first it didn't work but thankfully you mentioned it should be ApiController. That made me go back and look that I was inheriting from a BaseController and that controller was a "Controller" type and not "ApiController". Changed to ApiController and it worked. Good learning moment for me!